# Determinar numeros primos con tabla de multplicar

Tags: php

Me queda establecer que aparezca la tabla de multiplicar del número que sea primo

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    if(primo($i))
        echo '<div style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">' .  " ".$i." es un primo ". "<br/>"   ;

    else
        echo '<div style="color:red"; font-weight:bold;>' . " ".$i." NO es número primo " . "<br/>";

    //
}


/**

 * Función que determina si un numero es primo

 * Tiene que recibir el numero a determinar si es primo o no

 * Devuelve True o False

 */

function primo($num)

{
    $cont=0;

    // Funcion que recorre todos los numero desde el 2 hasta el valor recibido

    for($i=2;$i<=$num;$i++)
    {
        if($num%$i==0)
        {
            # Si se puede dividir por algun numero mas de una vez, no es primo
            if(++$cont>1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;


}

?>
```

Comment: Si he entendido bien, lo que quieres hacer es que se pida un numero y que te diga si es numero primero o no, y si lo es que te haga su tabla de multiplicar? no entiendo bien lo de multiplicar.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui esta como buscar numero primo, lo de hacer la tabla de multiplicar el numero es cuento.

```
    <?php

for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{
    if(primo($i))
        echo "El número ".$i." es primo";
    else
        echo "El número ".$i." NO es primo";
}
/**

 * Función que determina si un numero es primo

 * Tiene que recibir el numero a determinar si es primo o no

 * Devuelve True o False

 */

function primo($num)

{
    $cont=0;

    // Funcion que recorre todos los numero desde el 2 hasta el valor recibido

    for($i=2;$i<=$num;$i++)
    {
        if($num%$i==0)
        {
            # Si se puede dividir por algun numero mas de una vez, no es primo
            if(++$cont>1)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo no has entendido bien que es un numero primo, el programa que has puesto lo que hace es que te dice si el numero es par o es impar(pero no si es primo o no)

primo es todo aquel numero que solo sea divisible por la unidad(que se puede dividir por uno(todos los numeros son divisibles por uno)) y por el mismo

por lo tanto un numero pirmo tiene 2 y solo 2 divisores, excepto el 1 que tambien cumple con la condicion pero tiene un solo divisor

```
$numero;
$cantdedivisores=0;

for($i=1;$i<=$numero;$i++){
  if($numero%$i==0){
    $cantdedivisores++;
  }
}

if(cantdedivisores==1 && cantdedivisores==2){
  echo "el numero".$numero."es primo";
}
```

Lo de las tablas no lo he entendido muy bien, si lo pudieras explicar mejor, te ayudaria sin ningun problema, Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Hola gracias. Sí lo que no consigo es que me imprima por pantalla la tabla de multiplicar cuando me detecte que el número sí es primo. Por ejemplo: 7 es  primo, y a continuación su tabla de multiplicar

Answer (score 0):

Esta función viene de un post en la versión en [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16763365/1684426) de SO, en resumen:

1. El número uno **no es primo**
2. El número dos **si es primo**, es el único número par que es primo.
3. Si el numero es divisible por dos quiere decir que **no es primo**
4. Revisando los impares si se obtienen factores entonces **no es primo**.
5. Pasadas estas pruebas, el resultado sería un número primo.

.

```
function isPrime($num) {
    if($num == 1)
        return false;

    if($num == 2)
        return true;

    if($num % 2 == 0) 
        return false;

    $ceil = ceil(sqrt($num));
    for($i = 3; $i <= $ceil; $i = $i + 2) {
        if($num % $i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```